# Log variable as asterisks in VSTS Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am writing a VSTS extension using Typescript.

In vsts-task-lib I am using the function execSync which prints the executed command. Till here it's alright.

The issue is that in this command I am using a token that I obtain using a service, and I want the token to be printed as ********* instead of his real value.

If I use a token provided as a password field, it is print as asterisks by default.

Is there a way that I can do it with the token obtained by a service?

Some idea of how to create a "secret" variable in Typescript? If by default the password fields are print as asterisks there has to be some property or workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `##vso[task.setvariable]value` [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

> Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task
>   can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable.
>   The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment
>   variable. When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will
>   be saved as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not
>   passed into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as
>   inputs.

Examples:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true;]testvalue
```